# Web app on home screen (iphone style)?

Tags: android

just wondering when I had an iphone I was able to create a web app then place some code in it so that when the user pressed "add to homescreen" an icon would be placed on the home screen and when the user clicked it the web app would run full screen (no web navigation bar) so it just looked like a normal app (although it would only run with the web on) Is there anyway I can do this with android or do I have to code a whole app to do it? Sorry if this is a bit unclear. Thanks, Adam.

What I used for the iphone:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/myCustomStartupGraphic.png" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. A workaround is to make a really simple app containing only a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/search.html#q=WebView&t=0) and load into this webView your URL and then publish this app into the Play Store.

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.loadUrl("http://awesome.website.com");
```

Then on your website you can use the HTTP User agent to redirect users to download this app on Android devices.

Comment: I've given the bounty to this answer. Although it isn't as simple as the iPhone attribute method, this does actually give us what we want and as Android doesn't cost $99/year it isn't too bad that we might need to add it to the Play store. It still means we only have one HTML5 app and we shouldn't ever need to update our Play app as it just loads a web page.

Answer (score 1):

You can now add pages as apps to the homescreen in Chrome Beta for Android.  This is new as of Chrome M31 Beta.  I'm not sure when it will be moved into mainstream Chrome for Android.  To find Chrome Beta I couldn't just search the Play store, but instead had to do a regular Google search in Chrome. That result linked to Chrome Beta in the Play store.

Check out the info here to add a homescreen option: 
https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/installtohomescreen

This is all I did to get this working:

1. Add this meta tag to the `<head>`:

   `<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`
2. Add this image link to the `<head>` for the homescreen icon:

   `<link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="114x114" href="views/img/icon114x114.png" />`

I had the icon already made in a few sizes and ended up using one at 114x114.  I found that the 512x512 version of the icon I was using for iOS didn't work for me in Chrome, with either `sizes="512x512"` or `sizes="114x114"` set in the `<link>`.  Google's recommended size is 196x196.

If you have any issues, the Google Remote Debugger is awesome for troubleshooting. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging

Answer (score 0):

You can add a webpage as a bookmark, and from there add it to your homescreen. This, however, will not give it fullscreen. Last time I checked, you'll need a 3rd party app for that.

Comment: yeah I did the bookmark thing , but was a bit disappointed when it ran with the menu bar and such. Does anyone know if there is an inbuilt function or something for this? I read about a webview is this something I can just put inside an empty app to display my webpage in?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think is this possible as the way the homescreen app launches a different app is via the Launcher intent. If your 'app' is just a URL it would then be picked up by whatever browser is setup to listen to URLs like the stock browser, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Dolphin or whatever. As each has its own configuration you won't be able to remove the 'chrome' of the web navigation bar consistently.

You would have to use PhoneGap/Cordova to make a wrapper app but realize that the embedded webview isn't as full featured as a full blown browser app so testing is always recommended.